# Reading Nested Json into Pandas error

Tags: python, json, pandas

I couldn't read this specific Json file properly as a Pandas Dataframe. I've used similar code for the rest of other JSON samples - which works perfectly, however I need some help in understanding what could be wrong here.

The nested "traits" cannot be read directly and throws an error. The actual table looks like this:

[Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5PhY.png)

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open("./assessment/0144209a-32ee-4114-bc69-9912dd3dde5c.json") as f:
    d = json.load(f)

df = json_normalize(d['results'])
df.head(10)

works_data = json_normalize(data=data['results'], record_path='traits')
works_data.head()
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 works_data = json_normalize(data=data['results'], record_path='traits')
>         2 works_data.head()
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\normalize.py
>   in json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix,
>   errors, sep)
>       257                 records.extend(recs)
>       258 
>   --> 259     _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
>       260 
>       261     result = DataFrame(records)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\normalize.py
>   in _recursive_extract(data, path, seen_meta, level)
>       233         else:
>       234             for obj in data:
>   --> 235                 recs = _pull_field(obj, path[0])
>       236 
>       237                 # For repeating the metadata later
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\normalize.py
>   in _pull_field(js, spec)
>       180                 result = result[field]
>       181         else:
>   --> 182             result = result[spec]
>       183 
>       184         return result
>
> KeyError: 'traits'

Comment: Provide data as text

Comment: May I know if I should pass it as String and if yes, how ?

Comment: [Python Json loads() returning string instead of dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25613788)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a small syntax error in the variable name. You included ***data*** instead of ***d*** on row 11. 
Switch the following:

```
data=data['results']
```

To this:

```
data=d['results']
```